# pyqtgraph plot not filling whole widget (from qt designer)

Tags: qt, pyside, qt-designer, pyqtgraph, pyside6

I'm trying to embed a pyqtgraph plot in my PySide6 app but the plot is not filling the whole widget:

[image]

I want the whole PlotWidget to be filled. The PlotWidget got created with QT-Designer.

The App:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window = QUiLoader().load("test.ui", self)
        self.plot_widget = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(parent=self.window.graphicsView)
        self.plot_widget.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

The test.ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="PlotWidget" name="graphicsView"/>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <customwidgets>
  <customwidget>
   <class>PlotWidget</class>
   <extends>QGraphicsView</extends>
   <header>pyqtgraph</header>
  </customwidget>
 </customwidgets>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

So how can I make the plot fill the whole widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for the UI file.

You will get the desired result by simply creating the `plotWidget` and setting it as the `centralWidget` for the `mainWindow`.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.plot_widget = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget()
        self.plot_widget.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
        self.setCentralWidget(self.plot_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    MW.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

I am not very familiar with using UI files with `pyqtgraph`, but it appears to me that the UI file is automatically generating a `QGraphicsView` right were you want to put your `PlotWidget`.  So one way of making it work would be to deleting the `QGraphicsView` and replacing it in the layout with your `PlotWidget`.

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import pyqtgraph


class WindowUi:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = QUiLoader().load("test.ui")
        layout = self.window.verticalLayout
        item = layout.takeAt(0)
        item.widget().deleteLater()
        self.plot_widget = pyqtgraph.PlotWidget(parent=self.window.graphicsView)
        layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.plot_widget.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = WindowUi()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: I included the UI file because I use it in my app. The code I provided is just a minimal example. Is there a way to make it work using the UI file?

Comment: @Alexander But that new code would actually create *another* window, thus making `MainWindow` quite useless.

Comment: @musicamante  I don't know what you mean?  which example are you referring to?

Comment: @Alexander In your second example you're creating a `MainWindow` instance, but you're not really using it, since what is actually being shown is the one created by QUiLoader. That QMainWindow is useless right now.

Comment: Oh... good point.  I didn't even consider that when I copied the code. @musicamante I will fix

Comment: @jamesB  You may want to take a look at the alterations I made to the second example.  There is no need to subclass QMainWindow since the Uiloader already creates one for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use PyQtGraph's helper method to load your `.ui` file instead (per [this PythonGUIs tutorial](https://www.pythonguis.com/tutorials/pyside6-embed-pyqtgraph-custom-widgets/)); this will prevent the `qt.pysideplugin` warnings at startup as PyQtGraph widgets are handled properly and renders the plot in the whole widget as expected.

```py
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
import pyqtgraph


class MainWindow(*pyqtgraph.Qt.loadUiType("test.ui")):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.graphicsView.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
        self.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MW = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image: PyQtGraph plot rendering as expected]